# Is there any relationship between avalanche and permutation in block ciphers?

Tags: permutation, avalanche

Avalanche is one of the characteristics of S-Box or SP network(S and P boxes are used together).Is it possible for the permutation module, when tested alone, to show avalanche effect.? reference  SP network in block ciphers

Comment: your question is incomprehensible as it stands.

Comment: It would be odd if the avalanche effect was unrelated to the permutation.

Comment: Hint: the composition of permutations is a permutation. This is enough to answer the question.